# How do I see delayed_job jobs in production?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, capistrano, delayed-job, production

I'm have a server where I deploy using capistrano and I use delayed_jobs to do some mailing but at my server for some reason the jobs do not execute. The delayed_job process is running (running `bin/delayed_job status` answers me correctly saying there's a process there by some pid), but I don't know if the process just isn't executing my jobs or even if my jobs aren't being enqueued. Locally it all works fine, but at production staging in the server it does not.

I'd like to know if there's a way I can at least check what jobs are there, since I can't do it by accessing the console

Comment: So, did you start delayed_job as `production environment` ?
`RAILS_ENV=production script/delayed_job start`

Comment: Do you have delayed job web installed?  https://github.com/ejschmitt/delayed_job_web

Comment: Yes It restarts the process every time I deploy. I started doing `RAILS_ENV=production script/delayed_job run` to see what was happening and I found out it was getting connection time out when trying to send the emails. So I figured it was a problem with the port I was using (587) and the server (digital ocean), from that I ran `telnet smtp.mailgun.org 587` and it was taking a lot of time to connect. Well I changed the port to 2525, which connected instantly through telnet's command, but it still throws me connection timeout... 

It got far from the original post so I'll create another ques.

Comment: Oh wow awesome gem, thanks, i'll probably add that

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok so I'm checked my jobs through the database itself, I entered psql through postgres user and did some queries in the delayed_jobs table, you can also try doing `RAILS_ENV=production bin/delayed_jobs run` (for rails 4, rails 3 use "script/" instead of "bin/") which will show you what the workers are doing while they execute the job.

You can also, as Swards commented above, use a gem to have a web interface for delayed_jobs: https://github.com/ejschmitt/delayed_job_web

If you still wanna see what was my problem with the email sending I've opened another question because it got to far away from what this one was about: [What port to use sending email with SMTP (mailgun) in rails app on production server (DigitalOcean)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37754031/what-port-to-use-sending-email-with-smtp-mailgun-in-rails-app-on-production-se)

Answer (score 2):

Another gem that works with delayed job is delayed-web which you can find here https://github.com/tatey/delayed-web

you add it to your gemfile

```
gem 'delayed-web'
```

then run

```
rails generate delayed:web:install
```

this will generate an initializer file delayed_web.rb under config/initializers with the following:

```
Rails.application.config.to_prepare do
  Delayed::Web::Job.backend = 'active_record'
end
```

and in config/application.rb this will be added for you as well by the generator

```
# config/application.rb
config.assets.enabled = true
config.assets.precompile << 'delayed/web/application.css'
```

In routes.rb it may add a route as well but if you are using devise then maybe you want to restrict access to admin user(s) only as follows:

```
authenticated :user, -> user { user.admin? } do
  mount Delayed::Web::Engine, at: '/jobs'
end
```