# What port to use sending email with SMTP (mailgun) in rails app on production server (DigitalOcean)?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, port, capistrano, digital-ocean, mailgun

I have a rails app deployed at a digital ocean droplet configured with capistrano and mailgun, but I'm having trouble sending emails, task which I do using delayed_jobs. The thing is every time it tries to send an email I get connection timeout (verified using `RAILS_ENV=production bin/delayed_jobs run`in the server) and I found out that for some reason digital ocean does not allow from default for you to access through port 587 (and indeed, running `telnet smtp.mailgun.org 587` takes a very long time to access) but apparently trough port 2525 you can (mailgun also supports that port and running `telnet smtp.mailgun.org 2525` connects instantly!). But again, it still gives me connection timeout, so I'm kind of confused and don't know what to do. I'll probably send a ticket to DO asking to open port 587, until then do you have any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Digital Ocean blocks SMTP for safety reasons, based on the CAN SPAM Act (https://www.ftc.gov/tips-advice/business-center/guidance/can-spam-act-compliance-guide-business), so if you want to send emails using SMTP in their servers you'll need to send a ticket asking to unblock it with some infos about yourself so they verify your not just some crazy guy trying to flood people mail boxes or a robot.

Hope it helps! Good luck